# Category of Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, hilbert-spaces, homological-algebra

Is it possible to triangulate the category of Hilbert spaces and bounded linear operators?

I assume that one candidate for triangulation is the double dual space.

What is a fact is that this category is additive, which is nice.

Comment: Isn't it already abelian?

Comment: It seems unlikely. The kernel of a bounded linear operator is a closed subspace, but I don't think the image of a bounded linear operator is necessarily closed.

Comment: No, because you do not have cokernels in general, unless your linear map has a closed image.

Comment: When you say "triangulate" do you mean "endow with a triangulated structure"?

Comment: Marco: It is a common misconception to think that there are no cokernels. Every morphism $T\colon X \to Y$ has the projection $Y \to Y/\mathop{cl}(T(X))$ as cokernel since every map $S\colon Y \to Z$ such that $ST = 0$ must be zero on the closure $\mathop{cl}(T(X))$ of the image $T(X)$. It is easy to check that this projection has the universal property. The cokernels are simply different from the ones you're used to from linear algebra. The category is not abelian since there are morphisms which are monomorphisms and epimorphisms but not isomorphism (take any injection with dense range).

Comment: Since Hilbert spaces are reflexive, the bidual won't give an interesting triangulation.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, I would have think thats a very good reason to take it as a triangulation.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg why do you say that?

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: Yes I do.